# Need help on “Regular expression” catch any illegal characters

Tags: regex, oracle, unix

I need to catch any illegal character that invalid in Unix filename such as space , but excluding Japanase, Chinese character, etc (those are valid character in Unix filename) using regular expression. Please advise what should be the right regular expression.

Ex:

Source string: `RE  MCS CONS対応依頼（CarePack購入希望 ありたみつのぶ'様）`

Target String: It should not have any special charactors except valid japanese Chinese characters.

I would like to replace spaces and spacial charactors with _ (Under score).
So the final string should have only english alpha numeric characters, _ (Under score), valid Japanese and Chinese chars. So that I use this final string as file name to create a file in UNIX.

Answer (score 2):

The only character that is invalid in a Unix file name is `/`, and it can be matched as itself in a regular expression.

If you want to match other characters you can use a character class.

Comment: +1. Note that the POSIX spec does not actually require implementations to accept all characters aside from `/` and `\0`, but many do. In particular, it doesn't require them to support Chinese, Japanese, etc., and it doesn't even require the use of any character coding that's even capable of expressing them.

Comment: Indeed, the implementations I'm familiar with treat file names as binary blobs, and it's the application's responsibility to make sense of them.

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply and let me try the 1st option i.e removing the / and create a file.

Comment: @Joni: I think "binary blobs" is misleading, because one major characteristic of binary blobs is that they allow null bytes, which filenames do not. Probably "arbitrary null-delimited strings" is a better description.